# Nginx bad gateway and connection errors

Tags: nginx

I've followed [this tutorial](http://maketecheasier.com/install-lemp-server-in-ubuntu/2012/05/29) for a basic installation of nginx.

I always get bad gateway errors and when i look at the logs i see :

> [error] 3226#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client

Here is my nginx.conf and contents of my sites-available/defaults

[nginx.conf,](http://pastie.org/5522546)
[defaults](http://pastie.org/5522554)

I am also seeing this error :

> conflicting server name "explorable.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, PHP5-FPM

Thank you!

Comment: Is `php5-fpm` actually running and listening to 127.0.0.1 on port 9000?

Comment: How do i know that? Sorry Im very much new to PHP-FPM /Nginx combo

Comment: The command `sudo netstat -tlnp | egrep "php5-fpm|9000"` displays any running process called `php5-fpm` or listening on port 9000.

Answer (score 1):

Check if php-fpm is really running with e.g. `ps aux | grep php`. You can start and stop php-fpm with `/etc/init.d/php-fpm start|stop|restart`.